# Cross-referencing within a Table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have defined a new counter to track chemical reactions listed in a Table

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{clccr} \hline
\#   & Reaction                           &  $\log_{10}A$ &  $n$  & $E_A$ \\ \hline
\rxn & 2(3H)-furanone $\to$~2-propenal + CO               &  23   & 1.234 & 202.3 \\
\rxn & 2(3H)-furanone $\to$~4-oxo-3-butenal               &  23   & 1.234 & 202.3 \\ 
\rxn & 2(3H)-furanone $\to$~2-butenedial                  &  23   & 1.234 & 202.3 \\
\rxn & 2(3H)-furanone $\to$~2-furanol                     &  23   & 1.234 & 202.3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{High-pressure limit rate constant parameters; units: s$^{-1}$, kJ mol$^{-1}$}
\label{kinetics}
\end{table}
```

But how can I cross-reference?  For example, in the main text `reaction~\ref{a} has a much higher barrier than reaction~\ref{d} ...`

LaTeX and plain old article class; the counter is set in the preamble as:

```
\newcounter{iso} % A new counter to track chemical reactions aka "equations"
\setcounter{iso}{1} %
\newcommand{\rxn}{(\oldstylenums{\theiso})\stepcounter{iso}}% Tabular numbering
```

John

Answer (score 4):

You need `\refstepcounter` not `\stepcounter` and to use that *before* printing the number with `\theiso`, so also delete the line

```
\setcounter{iso}{1} %
```

you can then go `\rxn\label{foo}`  for any row that you need to reference and  `\ref{foo}` will reference it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` to increment the counter variable `iso`, *and* you need to provide a `\label` instruction after the "iso" counter is incremented (and displayed).

You can get automatically generated labels if you provide following instructions in the preamble:

```
\newcounter{iso}
\newcommand{\rxn}{\refstepcounter{iso}%
                  \label{iso:\theiso}%
                  (\oldstylenums{\theiso})}
```

You can then cross-reference the third "equation" by typing

```
\ref{iso:3}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want symbolic-name rather than automatic-name `\label`s associated with some or all of the "equations", you can get them the old-fashioned way, i.e., by typing `\label{rxn:whatever}` in the cell *after* `\rxn`.

I assume you'll want to have the cross-referenced numbers typeset in "oldstyle" and surrounded by parentheses. If you have more than just a couple of such cross-references, it pays to set up a dedicated macro called, say, `\osref` (short for "oldstyle \ref") to simplify creating these cross-references:

```
\newcommand\osref[1]{(\oldstylenums{\ref{#1}})}
```

With this macro set up, you can type something like

```
As shown by reaction~\osref{rxn:whatever}, \ldots
```

to generate the properly formatted cross-references.

Comment: automatic labelling is evil: if you know the number is 3 you can just use `3` no need for `ref{iso:3}` labels should be symbolic names disconnected from the numbering

Comment: Okay I would prefer symbolic labels but how does one achieve this? Displayed math mode is not possible within tabular (?) and text math does not allow labelling.  The reaction counter is still required because we are not sure how many items will appear in the final Table.

Comment: @JohnSimmie - Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @JohnSimmie Just use `\label` and `\ref` (although `\label` has to be in the first column as Mico has added, I noted that in my answer as well:-)